# Checking if array contains objects issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsarray

Why does this block of code not fire? The Array contains 0 objects, so i thought that the `array.count == 0` should have worked in this case.

[image]

Instead, the code goes to the `else` statement. What am i doing wrong? Or what might be causing this?

Code:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    if (!newEvents || newEvents.count == 0)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
    else
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
else
{
    if (!oldEvents || oldEvents.count == 0)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
    else
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

**Edit**

After looking further into it, i have found that this is not firing, making it seem the other is not:
[image]

Here is some more code that might be important to you.

[image]

Comment: Can you copy paste more code?

Comment: Yea, sure. One moment.

Comment: @AntonioMG I added some more code, and even something i figured out. But i still do not know why the new issue has occurred.

Comment: Your code looks OK to me and incidentally the `!newEvents` check is not necessary as `newEvents.count` will return `0` if `newEvents == nil`.  This should at least simplify your code slightly.

Comment: Whoever downvoted and voted to close, could you please tell me what i am doing wrong, since this question seems unnecessary?

Comment: @trojanfoe Why does `indexPath.section` not sire?

Comment: The code you are providing doesn't help at all. Could you paste what happens before your failing "if", please?

Comment: @EliteGamer I don't see why it wouldn't fire.  As I say, all the code you posted looks OK.  It's time to widen the search...

Comment: While the debugger clearly states that the array has 0 objects I have occasionally experienced that it can be a bit flakey in what it reports. (Even as far as reporting local objects to be nil on the same line as it is actually logging the information that it exits). Have you tried logging the array inside the if, to see if it might actually contain something after all?

Comment: try putting else if for the second if statement. I think your if / else logic is wrong here.

Comment: why don't you just NSLog every branch and see where it actually goes?